# Why is iptables not blocking an IP address? (LB/proxy version)

Tags: apache-2.2, iptables, fail2ban, amazon-elb

WARNING: Long. Lots of info here.

3 years ago someone asked [Why is iptables not blocking an IP address?](https://serverfault.com/questions/523021/why-is-iptables-not-blocking-an-ip-address) and it turned out the reason was because the servers were behind CloudFlare which made it impossible to block IP addresses directly they way they wanted to unless you use it differently.  Any reverse proxy or load balancer would cause the same thing.

Similarly we have setup fail2ban with a rule to ban any bots which attempt to brute-force their way into the administrative login or spam xmlrpc.  The site is sitting behind a load balancer so obviously we can't directly ban the IP address but iptables is supposed to be accepting the connection and pattern matching the packet data to ban specific traffic.

This is fail2ban jail.conf config:

```
[wp-auth] 
enabled = true
filter = wp-auth
action = iptables-proxy[name = lb, port = http, protocol = tcp]
         sendmail-whois[name=LoginDetect, dest=ITemail@ourdomain.com, sender=acceptablebotbot@ourdomain.com, sendername="Fail2Ban"]
logpath = /obfuscated/path/to/site/transfer_log
bantime = 604800
maxretry = 4
findtime = 120
```

This is the simply pattern match for wp-login requests:

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> .* "POST /wp-login.php
ignoreip = # our ip address
```

This is our fail2ban iptables action which is supposed to be able to block these bots but for the most part doesn't seem to.  It is from the CentOS site Tips section for [fail2ban behind a proxy](https://centos.tips/fail2ban-behind-a-proxyload-balancer/). For the sake of brevity I've left only the section header comments in place.

```
# Fail2Ban configuration file
#
# Author: Centos.Tips
#

[INCLUDES]

before = iptables-blocktype.conf

[Definition]

# Option:  actionstart
actionstart = iptables -N fail2ban-<name>
              iptables -A fail2ban-<name> -j RETURN
              iptables -I <chain> -p <protocol> --dport <port> -j fail2ban-<name>

# Option:  actionstop
actionstop = iptables -D <chain> -p <protocol> --dport <port> -j fail2ban-<name>
             iptables -F fail2ban-<name>
             iptables -X fail2ban-<name>

# Option:  actioncheck
actioncheck = iptables -n -L <chain> | grep -q 'fail2ban-<name>[ \t]'

# Option:  actionban
actionban = iptables -I fail2ban-<name> 1 -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --algo bm --string 'X-Forwarded-For: <ip>' -j DROP

# Option:  actionunban
actionunban = iptables -D fail2ban-<name> -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --algo bm --string 'X-Forwarded-For: <ip>' -j DROP

[Init]
# Default name of the chain
name = default

# Option:  port
port = http

# Option:  protocol
protocol = tcp

# Option:  chain
chain = INPUT
```

So as I mentioned the site is on a pair of servers behind an elastic load balancer and seems to work in test.  We can add any of our own IP addresses and we cannot reach the site.  Despite this bots seem to be able to get through.

```
[root:~/] iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N fail2ban-SSH
-N fail2ban-lb
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j fail2ban-lb
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j fail2ban-SSH
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 5666 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 24007:24020 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A fail2ban-SSH -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-lb -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m string --string "X-Forwarded-For: 91.200.12.33" --algo bm --to 65535 -j DROP
-A fail2ban-lb -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m string --string "X-Forwarded-For: 91.134.50.10" --algo bm --to 65535 -j DROP
-A fail2ban-lb -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m string --string "X-Forwarded-For: 160.202.163.125" --algo bm --to 65535 -j DROP
-A fail2ban-lb -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m string --string "X-Forwarded-For: 162.243.68.232" --algo bm --to 65535 -j DROP
-A fail2ban-lb -j RETURN
```

Port 80 is the only port open to all.  All others are ACL'd via AWS Security Groups.  IPtables appears to be processing in the correct order and should therefore be blocking these IPs based on their X-Forwarded-For header.  There is a Firefox plugin which allows you to send these headers with initial requests and we get blocked as a result with any of these bot IPs as well.

The source IP address does not appear to be forging the X-Forwarded-For header as we've been playing with as the ELB rewrites them anyway.  tcpdump does not show any extra information on the packet at the server level.

```
22:07:14.309998 IP ip-10-198-178-233.ec2.internal.11054 > ec2-10.4.8.71.http: Flags [P.], seq 2545:3054, ack 19506, win 166, options [nop,nop,TS val     592575835 ecr 2772410449], length 509
E..1..@.@..9
...
f.p+..P.Nz.
20............
#Q.[.?.QPOST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1
host: www.thiswebsite.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: zh-cn
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://www.thiswebsite.com/wp-login.php
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; 125LA; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022)
X-Forwarded-For: 91.200.12.33
X-Forwarded-Port: 80
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
Content-Length: 21
Connection: keep-alive
```

These requests are all being logged in the transfer_log. 
When we do the same thing and forge the X-Forwarded-For we get caught by iptables before ever reaching Apache. tcpdump also shows our extra IPs.

```
20:10:25.378873 IP ip-10-198-178-233.ec2.internal.11054 > ec2-10.4.8.71.http: Flags [P.], seq 3157:3860, ack 124583, win 267, options [nop,nop,TS     val 526293643 ecr 2507283790], length 703
E...Tf@.@.[.
...
f.p,O.P...GU........m.....
.^...r.QPOST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1
host: www.thiswebsite.com
Accept: /
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cookie: __utma=190528439.16251225.1476378792.1478280188.1478289736.3; __utmz=190528439.1476378792.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none);     _icl_current_language=en; __utmc=190528439; __utmb=190528439.2.10.1478289736; __utmt=1
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://www.thiswebsite.com/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0
X-Forwarded-For: 91.200.12.33, <our ip address>
X-Forwarded-Port: 80
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
Connection: keep-alive
```

I also have the ELB access log here which I expect to see an entry for, just not the Apache transfer logs.

```
2016-11-07T22:07:14.309917Z mLB 91.200.12.33:60407 10.4.8.71:80 0.000079 1.99244 0.000091 200 200 21 3245 "POST http://www.thiswebsite.com:80/wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; 125LA; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022)" - -
```

So the IP address (at least according to the ELB) does not appear to be forced at the X-Forwarded-For level.  Why is traffic from it not being blocked?  The IP address also shows up constantly in the fail2ban log with the usual:

```
fail2ban.actions[11535]: INFO [wp-auth] 91.200.12.33 already banned
```

Comment: *"The site is sitting behind a load balancer so obviously we can't directly ban the IP address*" - why not? Have you considered that fail2ban rather than calling iptables one can also use the `actionban=` to call another script/program/API function to get your loadbalancer/firewall to block te client at the ip-level? You're not rstricted to using the host based firewall on the server running fail2ban.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I'm having the same problem. I've added a bounty.

Comment: How is apache writing it's logs for fail2ban to pick up?  Normally x-forwarded-for is a list of addresses and the last one in the list is the client.  It's possible that fail2ban is picking up the wrong ip to ban from the log.

Comment: Haven't tried it but does this help? https://centos.tips/fail2ban-behind-a-proxyload-balancer/

Comment: Also:  http://www.loadbalancer.org/blog/apache-and-x-forwarded-for-headers

Comment: Apache writes to access.log and Fail2ban is picking up the right IP address and adding it to iptables. You can see in the question iptables `DROP`s the packet but users are still able to browse/login to the site.

Comment: The article you linked to is the one being used and linked to in the question.

Comment: It was mentioned I could script a call to the ACL in the AWS Load Balancer but as it happens this only works with a load balancer with classic mode enabled serving servers within a VPC.  It does not appear that you can use the ACL on VPC load balancers and connect to Classic Instance servers.  The load balancer specifically setup for classic instance servers does not have an ACL capability attached to it.  It would be best if we just reprovision the servers under a VPC instead so we could do that but "budget" blah blah blah...etc. So unfortunately this issue is still unresolved.

Comment: It would be interesting to look at the size of the incoming packets to see if the bots are trying to use small packets/fragmentation to avoid detection.  A logging rule in the fail2ban-lp chain might also be helpful.

Comment: @BrandonXavier I'm testing this myself and I'm not sending small packets, plus iptables have flagged this.

Comment: @Abs Fair enough.  My comments were based on the tcpdump from the original poster which does not appear to be coming from the same client.  How is your iptables "flagging" it?  The rules appear to be correct yet apache still receives packets that should be dropped.  IMHO time to roll up your sleeves, grab some packet captures  and start manually tinkering with your rules to find out exactly where and how it's breaking down.

Comment: Tcpdump captures all port traffic, including dropped. Are you sure that the packet you captured from the intruder is the same packet that iptables passed? I could imagine trying to defeat this setup by sending cookies with increasingly longer strings until one of them resulted in a boundary break that splits the header with IP address into two packets. Is it possible you caught a packet without cookie that was dropped but there are others with cookies that were not dropped?

Answer (score 2):

Your iptables rules look fine. One can't tell for sure what they're passing, however, without logging accepts. Tcpdump won't tell you this because it runs on incoming before iptables runs. Since you have need of a load balancer, iptables-accept logs for port 80 would likely produce very large files that you'd need to manage carefully (for disk use) and you'd need scripts or other tools to analyze them. However, that's what you'd need to do to find out what's getting through.

What I can tell you from the above, though, is that there's an inherent leak problem in using network-packet string matching for application-level filtering. Packet boundaries do not respect application boundaries, so in a high-attack environment, some of these requests will leak through. This is a statistical effect. With enough requests directed at your system, the probability that some of them will be split into more than one packet increases. That alone can account for the leaks. Hackers can tilt the odds in their favor by inserting headers that increase packet size. But volume alone is enough.

For thorough filtering you need to filter at the application level. Apache provides several mechanisms for that. You can block users identified by fail2ban with a .htaccess rule for X-Forwarded-For. You can also filter in your Location directive. I don't see an option for doing this within fail2ban, nor a standalone utility that does this, but a custom script to sync fail2ban jail-ees with an apache filter would be one way to implement an application-level filter.

One more consideration: You posted rules for IPv4. If you're accepting IPv6 connections on port 80, you'll want to make sure those rules are also maintained.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like fail2ban isn't actually making the new rules you think it is.  When you see the "already banned" message, do you do an "iptables -L" and see the desired rule?  An "already banned" message indicates that your detection is working, but your firewalling is not.  If you see the rule, but it's not working, that means something about the rule doesn't work, and you need to re-think the rule.

Your failregex and ignoreip tells me you just want to block everyone who isn't from your ip addresses.  That sounds a lot simpler than using fail2ban.

In fact, does your admin console even need a load balancer?  99% of the traffic to that site must be baddies trying to crack in.  If you know what addresses to allow, and your failregex and ignoreip indicates you do, you could just make the admin console accessible directly, but only to allowed IPs.

Oh, hey, this isn't over SSL is it?  If it is, iptables can't read the X-Forwarded-For header.

I really like HBruijn's idea about using cloudflares' API.  They should be doing the blocking, not you.

Finally, if you decide to do the filtering at the apache level, mod_rewrite has [rewrite maps](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html) which are great for this.  The dbd and prg features enable you to change the mapping without restarting apache.

Hope some of that helps

-Dylan